# Presenting selenium test info

Tags: selenium

I am making GUI tests to my web application using Selenium. I also want to store information about what they test and so far I have been writing text about their purpose, what they test and so on.

Problem with my current approach is that whenever business rules change, I also have to update information about the tests and make changes into code. But this approach is very tedious and it takes lot of effort to keep them up to date (text information about test).

So I was wondering, if there is some better way, how to keep them up to date? Maybe some use case diagrams?

Comment: You should specify test framework, programming language you use and example of how you store your tests description for now

Comment: Did you try some BDD frameworks like http://www.thucydides.info/#/ or https://cucumber.io?